# Target class [NotificationTypeSeeder] does not exist

Tags: laravel

i am calling a seeder class in the DatabaseSeeder in laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Database\Seeders\NotificationTypeSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(\Database\Seeders\NotificationTypeSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

this is my composer.json file

```
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
```

i am getting this error

```
  Target class [NotificationTypeSeeder] does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
  
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([NotificationTypeSeeder::class]);
    }
}
```